# Convergence of a bounded sequence towards limit $L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n : n \in \mathbb N)$ be a convergent sequence such that $a \leq a_n \leq b$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. I want to show that $a \leq lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n \leq b$. I know that to prove that a sequence converges to a limit $L \in \mathbb R$, you have to use an $\epsilon -N$ proof. In this case, let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given. My main question is, should I pick a limit $L$ such that $a \leq L \leq b$? If so, I would end up getting something like $|a_n - L| = |a_n + (-L)| \leq |a_n| + |-L| = |a_n| + |L| ...$

How does this work exactly?

Comment: The idea is that given any $\epsilon > 0$, if you're far enough into the sequence then $L - \epsilon < a_n < L + \epsilon$. So $a < L + \epsilon$ and $b > L - \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to use contradiction as you already know there's a limit, call it $L$, but you just want prove its value is within the bounds.

For any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists $a_n$ so that $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$, i.e., $-\epsilon \lt a_n - L \lt \epsilon$. If $L \lt a$, then if you choose $\epsilon \lt a - L$, you get $a_n - L \lt \epsilon \lt a - L \implies a_n \lt a$, which is not allowed. You can also do something similar to show that $L \gt b$ is not possible either.

This shows that $a \le L \le b$ must hold.